# Square root of a number... Accurate up to n precision

Tags: c++, algorithm, numerical-methods

[image: The method as found on Wikipedia]

[image: The method as found on Wikipedia]

I could not understand the above method. Can someone please explain? I have done some code but its is limited to some hard coded precision and seems to consume too much resource of computer.

```
R = 0.00001
INPUT N
WHILE R*R != N
        R = R + 0.00001
ENDWHILE
PRINT R
```

What is the Algorithm or C++ code for square root of a number upto n precision?
n can be taken from user if required.

Comment: Use the largest precision type you can (probably by using [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/) or similar library), then just print out with the desired precision. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Your code is in BASIC so far, and it doesn't really follow any of the algorithm described in your picture. What specific part do you have trouble understanding (if it's something mathematical, you could also ask on math.stackexchange.com). If this *isn't* homework, just use a `sqrt` function provided by a suitable library rather than writing your own.

Comment: Another means of finding square root: http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der07/der07.html

Comment: That algorithm is likely to NEVER work. At the very least, it should do `R*R <= N`, since it may well "go past" the right value by a smidgeon, and then it will run forever (or something tending towards forever at least).

Comment: @MatsPetersson The algorithm was designed for manual calculation, with exact decimal arithmetic, so there are no smidgeons involved. If the steps are followed correctly, the partial result will always be less than or equal to the square root of the input.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Sorry, I meant the code-sample, not the manual calculation algorithm.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, the code-sample has many problems.

Comment: @us2012 Yes it is a homework! :@ but thanks for math.stackexchange.com I thought just numerical-methods tag would work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are algorithms that are much better suited to computer evaluation. I learned the one in the question in the 1960's, as a way of manually calculating a square root digit-by-digit using a process rather like long division.

The objective, during calculation of the nth digit of the result, is to find the largest prefix string such that the square is less than or equal to the first 2n digits of the input.

The key underlying idea is that `(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab`. In the algorithm, `a` is the partial result so far, and `b` is the new digit. It accounts for factors of 100 in the square and 10 in the root by moving two places in the input for one generated digit in the result.

Let `p` be the partial result before appending digit `d`. We have already subtracted `p^2` from the input. We need to also subtract `d^2 + 2pd`, to maintain subtraction of the square of the new partial result. Equivalently, subtract `d(2p+d)`. We keep `p` already doubled, append `d`, and multiply by `d`. Before going on to the next step, we need to double `d` as well.

Comment: Yes binomial theorem is also an implementation but can you explain more about the long division process? Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of C++ code, although it is not arbitrary precision, it may be useful to you.  It is a little closer to a complete solution then your BASIC code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <climits>

const unsigned g_unPlaces = 8;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    std::cerr << "USAGE: " << *argv << " NUMBER" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::vector<unsigned> vecInteger;
  std::vector<unsigned> vecDecimal;
  char *pDecimal = strchr(argv[1], '.');

  // Read integer part of NUMBER
  if (pDecimal == NULL) pDecimal = argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]);
  if ((pDecimal - argv[1]) % 2) vecInteger.push_back(0);
  for (char *pCurrent = argv[1]; pCurrent < pDecimal; ++pCurrent)
  {
    int nValue = *pCurrent - '0';
    if (nValue >= 10 || nValue < 0)
    {
      std::cerr << "Error: Invalid character in input!" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    vecInteger.push_back((unsigned) nValue);
  }

  // Read decimal part of NUMBER
  if (*pDecimal != '\0')
  {
    for (++pDecimal; *pDecimal != '\0'; ++pDecimal)
    {
      if (*pDecimal == '.')
      {
        std::cerr << "Error: Multiple decimals in input!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }

      int nValue = *pDecimal - '0';
      if (nValue >= 10 || nValue < 0)
      {
        std::cerr << "Error: Invalid character in input!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
      vecDecimal.push_back((unsigned) nValue);
    }
    if (vecDecimal.size() % 2) vecDecimal.push_back(0);
  }

  const unsigned unInteger = vecInteger.size();
  const unsigned unDecimal = vecDecimal.size();

  std::vector<unsigned> vecValues;

  unsigned x, y = 0, c = 0, p = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < g_unPlaces; ++i)
  {
    if (2*i < unInteger-1)
    {
      c = (c*100 - y*100) + vecInteger[i*2]*10 + vecInteger[i*2+1];
    }
    else if (2*i < unInteger+unDecimal-1)
    {
      c = (c*100 - y*100) + vecDecimal[i*2-unInteger]*10
          + vecDecimal[i*2+1-unInteger];
    }
    else
    {
      c = c*100 - y*100;
    }

    if (c == 0) break;

    y = 0;
    for (x = 1; x < 10; ++x)
    {
      unsigned temp = x*(20*p + x);
      if (temp > c) { --x; break; }
      y = temp;
    }

    p = 10*p + x;
    vecValues.push_back(x);
  }

  // Write the result
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < unInteger/2; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << vecValues[i];
  }
  std::cout << '.';
  for (unsigned i = unInteger/2; i < vecValues.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << vecValues[i];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

As for help in understanding your algorithm, the best approach is to begin at the begging and work through each step.  Try with small values like 4, 16 and 64.  Go through the algorithm step by step with a piece of paper and a pencil and write down the parts for each step.

If your goal is only to calculate a number to N precision, then you would probably be better using an already made solution, change your problem so you don't need N precision or take a look at some of the other comments/answers.